# React-Native-Video onClick() prop

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am currently working on a react native app.
I am using react-native-video: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video

I could not find something like an onClick() prop.
What's the best way to implement a functionality for a click event on the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [touchablehighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html) like this :

```
class MyVideoComponent extends React.Component {

  videoPressed() {
    console.log("Video pressed");
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.videoPressed()}
      >
        <YOURVIDEOCOMPONENT/>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, please validate my answer if it matches your requirements.